# Macro-Constants not Working for arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arc

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\inRad{5};
            \def\outDist{3};
            \node[draw, circle, minimum size = \inRad cm](spacer){}; %5cm is diameter, not radius
            \def\angVal1{90};
            \draw(spacer.\angVal1) -- ++(\angVal1:\outDist cm) coordinate (place1);
            \def\angVal2{60};
            \draw(place1) arc(\angVal1 : \angVal2 :\inRad*.5cm + \outDist cm) coordinate (place2) -- (spacer.\angVal2);
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Is there a way to use macro-constants in the angle parameters for the `arc` command? Or constants declared as functions are the only option?

Comment: Constants are only written with letters, numbers are forbidden with TeX and LaTeX. For example write `angVala` and `angValb` instead of `angVal1` and `angVal2`.

Comment: Hmmmm ok. Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In TeX control word tokens can come into being in 3 ways:

1. Control word tokens can come into being as part of the replacement text of a macro.
2. Control word tokens can come into being as the result of expanding a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression. (You can consider `\ifcsname..\endcsname` of the εTeX-extensions a variant thereof.)
3. Control word tokens can come into being when TeX reads and tokenizes input from the .tex-input-file.

**When TeX tokenizes input from the .tex-input-file (way 3) only characters of category code 11(letter) will be considered components of the name of a control word token.**
**Digit-characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` usually have category code 12(other).**
Characters of category code 10(space)—usually the space-character and the horizontal-tab-character are of that category code—that in the .tex-input file follow sequences of characters that are tokenized as control word tokens are "dropped", i.e., don't yield any token.
Characters of category code 10(space) that follow sequences of characters that are tokenized as something other than a control word token or a space token usually yield an explicit space token, i.e., a character token of catcode 10(space) and charcode 32. (Explicit space tokens in turn may yield horizontal glue when processed while TeX is in horizontal mode or in restricted horizontal mode.)

**Therefore reading from the .tex-input-file and tokenizing the sequence `\angVal1`  usually yields a control word token `\angVal` followed by a character-token `112(other)`, followed by an explicit space token.**

**With tikz a single control sequence token is expected.**

As in other answers already proposed you can change `\angVal1`  to `\angValA`  and `\angVa2`  to `\angValB` :

At the time of reading and tokenizing input from the .tex-input file (way 3) all characters but the backslashes of the sequences `\angValA`  and `\angValB`  have category code 11(letter). Thus TeX will tokenize the sequence `\angValA`  from the .tex-input-file as single control-word-token `\angValA` and the sequence `\angValB`  from the .tex-input-file as single control-word-token `\angValB`. The space characters at the ends of these sequences will be dropped because they follow something that got tokenized as control word token.

Alternatively you can have TeX create the control word token for you from a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression (way 2). (The rules with way 3 do not apply with way 2.)

I don't like typing `\csname..\endcsname` and probably a lot of expansion-/`\expandafter`-trickery all the time.

Therefore in the example below I use a macro `\NameToCsToken` for this which "internally" applies `\csname..\endcsname`.

It is to be used as follows:

`\NameToCsToken⟨emptiness or tokens not in curly braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨emptiness or tokens not in curly braces⟩\NameOfCs`

E.g.,

`\NameToCsToken\newcommand*{macro?_42} ...` 
→
`\newcommand*\macro?_42 ...` 
; `\macro?_42` being a single control word token whose name is `macro?_42`.

Or, leaving the part before the opening-curly brace empty:

`\NameToCsToken{macro?_42}`
→
`\macro?_42`
; `\macro?_42` being a single control word token whose name is `macro?_42`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\NameToCsToken{\long\def\NameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCsToken{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCsToken[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\inRad{5}\def\outDist{3}%
            \NameToCsToken\def{angVal1}{90}%
            \NameToCsToken\def{angVal2}{60};
            \node[draw, circle, minimum size = \inRad cm](spacer){}; %5cm is diameter, not radius
            \draw(spacer.\NameToCsToken{angVal1}) -- ++(\NameToCsToken{angVal1}: \outDist cm) coordinate (place1);
            \draw(place1) arc(\NameToCsToken{angVal1}: \NameToCsToken{angVal2}: \inRad*.5cm + \outDist cm) coordinate (place2) -- (spacer.\NameToCsToken{angVal2});
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```